# What is the difference between $\nabla_{\boldsymbol\theta}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\theta}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

What is the difference between the gradient wrt $\boldsymbol\theta$ and the derivative wrt $\boldsymbol\theta $, or are they the same?

$$
\nabla_{\boldsymbol\theta} f(\boldsymbol\theta) \stackrel ? = \frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\theta} f(\boldsymbol\theta)
$$

Where
$$
\boldsymbol\theta = \begin{bmatrix} \theta_1 \\ \theta_2 \\ \vdots \\ \theta_n \end{bmatrix}
$$

The function I am examining is $f = \nabla _{\theta } \big [\text {Loss}_ h(y^{(i)}(\theta \cdot x^{(i)} + \theta _0) ) + \frac{\lambda }{2}\mid \mid \theta \mid \mid ^2 \big ] $, which I believe is $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, but I am interested in all cases.  I've worked with gradients of scalar functions before, which this seems to be ($f \stackrel ? = f(\theta_0, \theta_1, \theta_2, \cdots, \theta_n, x^{(i)}, \lambda)$), but the fact the variable of differentiation is a vector is throwing me off.

Coming from a programming background, I struggle to understand the types and arity of mathematical objects.  I am not quite understanding why we have different notation for the gradient and Hessian: Isn't the 1st and 2nd derivative just a special case of these?

Comment: There are multiple derivatives in higher dimensions. What do you mean by $D_\theta$? Is $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, or $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @DavidP: $D_{\pmb\theta} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \pmb\theta} f(\pmb\theta)$ and I was thinking $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, but am interested in understanding both.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your coordinate system.
In physics/engineering, the (spatial) gradient, usually denoted $\nabla$ or $\text{grad}$, generalises the derivative by describing the way a quantity changes in space and thus has units proportional to inverse length. Consider a polar coordinate system
$x = r\cos\theta, \ y = r\sin\theta $. The gradient operator is expressed as

$$\nabla f = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r}\hat{e}_r + \dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\hat{e}_\theta$$

Notice that the angle swept from the positive $x$-axis $\theta$, though used to describe the coordinate space,  does not have units of length. This is the hand-wavy intuition behind the $1/r$ factor appearing in front of $\partial_\theta f$, which gives that term the appropriate units.
More rigorously, the $1/r$ factor arises as a result of the metric that describes the polar curvi-linear coordinate system.

That's why in physics the $\nabla$ notation is used to denote gradients in general, because the components of the gradient are equal to $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ only in a cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: Is it not true in your example that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \nabla_r f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} = \nabla_\theta f$? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by $\nabla_rf$ and $\nabla_\theta f$?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I mean the gradient with respect to $r$ of $f$ and wrt $\theta$.

Comment: In this case, the gradient operator $\nabla$ contains information on how the function changes with respect to both the $r$ and $\theta$ coordinates, so it can loosely be thought of as a mapping $\nabla: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.